# Build apk failed with error: package android.arch.core.util does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I am encountering following error while building an apk:

```
error: package android.arch.core.util does not exist
```

My java code has a line:

```
import android.arch.core.util.Function;
```

I know this exists and its doc is [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/core/util/package-summary).

But how can I import it?

Answer (score 2):

There was a versioning problem and my problem solved with this link:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66894924#comment12

I used beta version of libs and it solved the error about `android.arch.core.util.Function;`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are using it for but here is a sample that compiles and runs. Add the import to the class that needs it and add the code somewhere in that same class. Android Studio would not let me import it until I had code that actually used it. It may be a bug or intentional.

**Import:**

```
import android.arch.core.util.Function;
```

**Code:**

```
Function function = new Function<Boolean, String>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(Boolean input) {
        return null;
    }
};
```

Comment: It gives an error for impoer line itself saying 'can not resolve symbol 'util''

Comment: Are you using Android Studio? If so, see if it lets you view the source code through the editor by clicking on the Function interface in the code in the answer. If not, then I need to see what you have imported in your build.gradle files.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have added the corresponding dependency in gradle

Example
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1"

Final answer

Add the below code in app/build.gradle file under "dependencies" block

```
// Room components 
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.0” 
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.0" 
androidTestImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.1.0" 
// Lifecycle components 
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0" 
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.0"
```

Comment: How can I find out what is corresponding line for module 'import android.arch.core.util.Function;' ?

Comment: It depends on the feature you are using in android architecture. You might be using one of the components from the here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/arch/. Let me know which component you are using, I can help you

Comment: **Add the below code in app/build.gradle file under "dependencies" block**

`// Room components
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.0”
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.0"
androidTestImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.1.0"

// Lifecycle components
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.0"`